# Can see open network in XP , but not connect. Only happened since arriving in Australia(!?) with multiple devices

Tags: windows-xp, networking, wireless-networking, router, netbook

I've had a netbook for a couple of years, while travelling, and it's fantastic. Little XP Asus netbook. Never had problems.

However since arriving in Australia (Melbourne) I've run into a couple of problems. I go to a coffee shop and can see their open wifi network in the list of networks, but if I try to connect to it - nothing. I can double-click it so that it's automatic, and in my list of preferred networks.  However, it just sits there ignoring it.

Now I'd start to wonder if it's my netbook, but I have a Nexus 4 as well, and it's been doing the same thing.  I'm not too fussed about the phone not connecting as I have data, but I really do need the netbook to work.  It connects to some just fine, and others - not.

I've run the repair tool.  I've even made my own batch file:

> route -f
>
> ipconfig /release
>
> ipconfig /renew
>
> arp -d *
>
> nbtstat -R
>
> nbtstat -RR
>
> ipconfig /flushdns
>
> ipconfig /registerdns

to just kinda reset everything and anything, which worked in Russia with a couple of dodgy routers that would drop me.

However, I've now run out of ideas.  Any theories?  If I really force it it'll just sit there for ages, give up, and give me the unassigned IP address if I check ipconfig /all.

I've tried self-assigning a static IP address, but usually I've not been able to guess their network range anyway.

Thoughts?

Comment: remember send and receive is reversed on the other hemisphere!  - Sorry has to say it

Comment: @Keltari no worries, I'm having a hard enough time adjusting to gravity being the other way around ;)